# Convert floor plan to 3D

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

I have tried this 2d to 3d floor plan conversion here:

https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-floor-plan-app

I got the conversion id in the end. What to do next?

I found out the conversion in firebase db status shows "IN_PROGRESS", will it change the conversion in firebase db status to "COMPLETED" automatically when it's completed?

Will I get the 3d ojbect file back?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On status update your node server will get a callback from the api server and triggers this function which sends the person that ordered the model an email with the url to the model:

```
if (status === 'COMPLETED') {
  console.log(`Floor plan conversion successful`)
  const sceneUrl = io3d.scene.getViewerUrl({ sceneId: conversionData.sceneId })
  const emailBody = `Your 3D model is ready: ${sceneUrl}`
  return sendEmailToCustomer(rpc, {
    to: [toEmail],
    from: configs.fromEmail,
    subject: 'Your 3D Model Is Ready',
    text: emailBody,
    html: emailBody
  })
}
```

the code can be adapted here:

https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-floor-plan-app/blob/master/api/on-conversion-status-update.js#L71

So basically you get back the sceneId in an url which opens the Archilogic viewer

`https://spaces.archilogic.com/3d/!<sceneId>`

Comment: so..It can just use in archilogic website and there is no 3d object to download..?

Comment: You can export it from there - in the near future there will also be an export API that you can use directly once it's available.

Comment: hey..I want to know when will I get the completed status back ? I have wait for 3 days and without any email back. lol

Comment: Could you give me the Order ID, then I'll double check our system

Comment: the conversionId: ea08657a-1280-44eb-bc63-e9630fdbd580, 95b7820c-1086-4bdd-aa19-7f49c1c6c0b1, 20e05ab9-cad9-406e-a70e-e9919a95f71d

Comment: Hey @KevinHu! We found a bug on our end preventing you from getting the update. Sorry for the hiccup and thank you for letting us know! We've re-triggered the update, so you should see the data in Firebase now.

If there are any other issues, please let us know! :)

Comment: @KevinHu we release the scene API which allows you to automatically import all assets from an Archilogic scene into A-Frame
https://3d.io/docs/api/1/scene.html
There is also an updated floor plan conversion documentation
https://3d.io/docs/api/1/convert-floor-plan-to-3d.html

Comment: @Frederic I have tried this feature and face some problem. I use "getAframeElements" api by my archilogic sceneId and append to my aframe it just nothing happen. I get 2 main a-entity, one with io3d-uuid. How can I use in aframe? following is my sceneId: 71c8eef9-b44e-447f-a0d2-fd299318da56

Comment: @KevinHu:
just do: `elements.forEach(el => sceneEl.appendChild(el))`
take a look at this example here:
https://appcreator.3d.io/qgP7tF?m=e

more complex example with navigation controls:
https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-js/blob/master/examples-browser/scene/index.html

you can also use the https://appcreator.3d.io to import scenes without any need to code